# encoding of Urdu text in Go

Tags: go, unicode, encoding

I have Urdu text and I want to encode it in Go.

A user name is like this

```
username := `ابو ناصر الحرسانی`
```

I read about the encoding package of Go but I'm not able to get my desired result. I want to read all the bytes and a string equivalent encoded value of this variable.

Comment: There is nothing to do here. You may freely use UTF-8 encoded urdu text in source. No "encoding" needed here. If you have a specific problem: Show code and what the code does and explain why you think this is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go uses UTF-8 encoding for the `string` type. Use `string` to convert a slice of UTF-8 encoded bytes (`[]byte`) to a UTF-8 encoded `string`. A `string` is a sequence of `byte`s; it is an immutable copy of the `byte` slice.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    username := `ابو ناصر الحرسانی`

    userbytes := []byte(username)
    fmt.Printf("%[1]T: %[1]v\n", userbytes)
    userstring := string(userbytes)
    fmt.Printf("%[1]T: %[1]v\n", userstring)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Ugwj-CxmQw0

Output:

```
[]uint8: [216 167 216 168 217 136 32 217 134 216 167 216 181 216 177 32 216 167 217 132 216 173 216 177 216 179 216 167 217 134 219 140]
string: ابو ناصر الحرسانی
```

Type `byte` is an alias of type `uint8`.

---

The Go Blog: [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Wikipedia: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Unicode: [UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)

Comment: thankyou for your response. I am having a little issue with printing the string in my console. Actually I want to write the desired output in a pdf but its not working. Its printing messy string. I tried to changed the format as per as the documentation (using %q and %s ) but still getting the messy output. Any solution for that?

Comment: If you are having problems with PDF output. that might be a limitation of the PDF package you are using (would have been useful to mention which one ;) ). For example *gofpdf* currently doesn't support UTF-8: "Like FPDF version 1.7, from which gofpdf is derived, this package does not yet support UTF-8 fonts. In particular, languages that require more than one code page such as Chinese, Japanese, and Arabic are not currently supported. [...] However, support is provided to automatically translate UTF-8 runes to code page encodings for languages that have fewer than 256 glyphs."

Comment: @rob74 yes I am using gofpdf and thankyou for your response. It solved my problem :)